# Visual Studio 2013 SerialPort not receiving all data

Tags: visual-studio, serial-port, pic, mplab

I am currently working on a project that requires serial communication between PIC 24FV16KA302 and a PC software.

I have searched the Internet for the past 3 days and i cant find an answer for my problem so i decided to ask here .  This is my first visual studio program so i dont have any experience with the software.

The PIC has few variables and two 8x16 tables that i need to view and modify on the PC side . The problem comes when i send the tables , all other information is received without a problem . I am using serial connection ( 38400/8-N-1 ) via uart to usb converter 
[FT232](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DTRFKM4)

When the PC send "AT+RTPM" to the PIC .

```
Button7.Click
    SerialPort1.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 128
    MachineState = MS.Receive_table
    SerialPort1.Write("AT+RTPM")
End Sub
```

The PIC sends back 128 Bytes( the values in the table )

```
case read_table_pwm : // send pwm table 
        for (yy = 0 ; yy < 8 ; yy ++) {
            for (xx = 0 ; xx < 16 ; xx++ ) {
                uart_send_char(controll_by_pmw_map_lb[yy][xx]) ;
            } 
        }
           at_command = receive_state_idle ;
    break ;
```

Which the software is suppose to get and display in a `DataGrid`.

```
Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    If MachineState = MS.Receive_table Then
        SerialPort1.Read(Buffer_array_received_data, 0, 128)
        cellpos = 0
        For grid_y As Int16 = 0 To 7 Step 1
            For grid_x As Int16 = 0 To 15 Step 1
                DataGridView1.Rows(grid_y).Cells(grid_x).Value = Buffer_array_received_data(cellpos)
                cellpos += 1
            Next
        Next

End Sub
```

The problem is that most of the time ( 99 % ) it displays only part of the dataset and zeros to the end  , and when i try to do it again it display the other part and it starts from the beginning .

[First request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffaJL.png)
[Second request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhaHs.png)

If i try the same thing with another program i always get the full dataset

[Realterm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKW6H.png)
[Termite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nts0C.png)

I have tried doing it cell by cell , but it only works if i request them one very second , other wise i get the same problem .

After that i need to use a timer ( 100 ms ) to request live data from the PIC . 
this work better but still some of the time i get some random data. I haven't focused on that for the moment because without the dataset everything else is useless .

Am i missing something or has anyone encountered the same problem ?

Comment: The SerialPort class in .NET has given me lots of problems talking to PIC MCUs as well.  Unfortunately the implementation of the SerialPort class is just not very...good.  

https://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport

That link might provide a few ideas for more reliable use of the SerialPort in .NET.  Be sure the check the comments out as well as there's further info in there.

Comment: There is no such thing as "all data", serial ports are byte-oriented.  So you can't ignore the return value of Read() and you have to call it as often as necessary to get all 128 bytes.  Do beware that you have a synchronization problem, if you start your PC program while the device is busy transmitting then the odds for getting garbage are 127 out of 128.  Normally solved with a protocol, like a unique byte that indicates the start of a frame.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by replacing

`SerialPort1.Read(Buffer_array_received_data, 0, 128)`

with

```
 For byte_pos As Int16 = 0 To 127 Step 1
     Buffer_array_received_data(byte_pos) = SerialPort1.ReadByte()
    Next
```

But aren't they supposed to be the same ?